# How to send and receive data to multiple android devices via wifi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct, file-sharing, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am looking for a step by step guide line regarding the following problem.

I want to connect more than 2 android devices via wifip2p/wifi-direct. For this I think we have to create a group and one of the devices has to be a group owner.

Then all other devices start sending images to each other and receiving images from all other devices. How to achieve that?

It seems broadcasting the image to all other devices is only possible for    group owner but then how a device which is not a group owner, will tell the    group owner to send images to all devices?

For Sending:
How the group owner will send the images to all other connected devices?

For Receiving:
How will all other devices get images from the group owner?

Answer (score 0):

follow the guide of [WiFi p2p](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). after WiFi p2p network created and devices connected, you can program just like in normal WiFi AP network.

How to send and recive data to multiple android device via wifi direct?

check the code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#transferring)

Comment: image or file just kind of data, which is byte[] or bytebuffer in Java. socket send data, ignoring the data format, not matter image,audio,video anything else.

Comment: yah i know but my point is that code is for sending data 
is any kind of we need that use for get data from group owner ?

Comment: group owner can control the connection, but just a normal peer in the group for data transfer. so think like your peers in same wifi ap and how to send data to peers? maybe udp broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this 
https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo
This is an extension of the wifidriect demo by android documentation where both group owner and client can send files and receive files

To extend the network over 2 devices you can detect who is the group owner in existing 2 device network and make sure that all new incoming devices connect to the group owner.